# How set static string value for CascadingValue in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

like as microsoft document you set static string for value in CascadingValue

[Blazor learning path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/interact-with-data-blazor-web-apps/6-share-data-in-blazor-applications)

But I couldn't do this, and in Visual Studio 2022 and .NET6, I have a syntax error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because razor syntax is searching a variable called Throwback Thursday.

Try using

```
 <CascadingValue Name="DealName" Value=@("Throwback Thursday")>
</CascadingValue>
```

This markup will take string value

Comment: `Value='"Throwback Thursday"'` will work too.